# findviewbyid for progressbar returning null

Tags: android, android-layout

I have added a progressbar in a RelativeLayout. See the xml below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_control_bar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FF6600">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/DetailHeading"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_margin="5dip"
            android:text="Product Details"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_control_bar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#FFFFFF">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnAddToCart"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
            android:minHeight="2dp"
            android:text="Add to Cart"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnWishlist"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
            android:minHeight="2dp"
            android:text="Add to Wishlist"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

       </RelativeLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottom_control_bar"
        android:layout_below="@id/top_control_bar"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/detImage"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="left">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/codelbl"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="1dp"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="Product Code:"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/detPCode"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="1dp"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="left">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/pricelbl"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="1dp"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="Price:"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/detPPrice"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="1dp"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="left">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/namelbl"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="1dp"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="Name:"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/detPName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="1dp"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="left">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/desclbl"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="1dp"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="Description:"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/detPDesc"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:ellipsize="none"
                    android:lines="5"
                    android:maxLines="2"
                    android:scrollHorizontally="false"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/detProgress"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/detHeaderProgress"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </ProgressBar>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now when I am trying to retrieve the ProgressBar in the onCreate of the activity, it is returning a null.

```
LinearLayout detHdrPgs = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.detProgress);
```

The `detHdrPgs` is null

I have done the setContentView of the activity already

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);
```

And is also able to retrieve the other elements like `btnAddToCart`

```
Button addCart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAddToCart);
```

Then why only ProgressBar is returning null?

The onCreate function code is as below

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    Button addCart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAddToCart);
    addCart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
         .....
        }
    });
     LinearLayout detHdrPgs = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.detHeaderProgress); detHdrPgs.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Thanks in advance for all the helps.

Answer (score 0):

`ProgressBar detHdrPgs = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.detHeaderProgress);`

In your onCreate you have:

```
LinearLayout detHdrPgs = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.detHeaderProgress);
```

You have to change it to:

```
LinearLayout detHdrPgs = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.detProgress);
```

Comment: sorry, that was a mistake, infact my code is LinearLayout detHdrPgs = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.detProgress);.That was something which i tried out , but not worked

Comment: No, this dint help. It still returns null. Also detHeaderProgress is the ProgressBar. I am trying to get the LinearLayout detProgress.

Comment: You've said in your question: Now when I am trying to retrieve the ProgressBar in the onCreate of the activity, it is returning a null. Then why only ProgressBar is returning null?

Comment: sorry if I confused you, I meant the LinearLayout enclosing the progressbar

Comment: try cleaning the project and the xml file. I just tried the code and it works ok. Try to put the LinearLayour before the ActionBar declaration. is it still null?

Comment: i am so sorry, it was a silly mistake, sorry i wasted your time. I was using different layouts for tablet and mobile and I added the ProgressBar in the mobile layout. I was testing in a tablet layout. I updated in both layouts and now its working.

Answer (score 0):

```
view.findViewById(R.id.detProgress)
```

What does `view` declare to?

Change it to

```
LinearLayout detHdrPgs = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.detProgress);
```

Did this help?

Comment: sorry, that was a mistake[I corrected the post]. I have actually used LinearLayout detHdrPgs = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.detProgress); But it is returning null.

Comment: You should change "findViewById(R.id.detHeaderProgress)" to "findViewById(R.id.detProgress)".